# Does "appear wrong" in this passage show meaning properly and is it correct?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to know whether the sentence below is alright, particularly the part in italic font.

> Why does my name *appear wrong* when the program is launched? My name is Tom, not Paul. I request to fix it.

Comment: Some people probably say it this way, but there should be an adverb after "appear". That would be *wrongly*, though I don't know if it is commonly used. The best word would be "incorrectly".

Comment: @user3169 Thank you for the comment. But what is wrong with just the adjective forms there? I have been taught that adjectives can be used after the verb "appear". Like, for instance, _She didn't appear at all surprised at the news_.

Comment: Actually, you're both right! It just depends on whether you mean appear as in "it suddenly showed up on the screen incorrectly" or "it looks wrong." You can see [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/appear) for more information. At first glance, I'm more inclined towards "look wrong," but I could see why technically, user3169 is correct because we're talking about the "sudden" appearance of our name at the moment the program is launched, so really, as is the case with most analyses for meaning, it's up to the speaker's what the speaker had intended.

Comment: *it's up to the speaker what the speaker had intended.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Thank you very much for your continuous help. I got your point! I understood. But, I can not follow this part of your words, "as is the case with most analyses for meaning". Can I ask you to give me a further explanation regarding it?

Comment: I had meant that there are always various opinions and perspectives which may be right on any level at any given time.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Thank you for the reply but, what do you mean by "at any given time"? Do you mean "according to the occasion it happens"?

Comment: Exactly. I think of it like [an optical illusion](https://www.moillusions.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Vase-Face1.png): "According to the occasion as it happens," the picture is a vase, it is also two faces facing each other and it is also both of these at the same time.